# Objective C How to to present AVPlayer with multiple filePath possibilities

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, video, avplayer

I am using `AVPlayer` to load up with no controls and act as an animation. With the background presenting the first and last screen of the animation.

When the `AVPlayerController` is presented, **the screen flashes black** for a split second as the controller loads up with the corresponding video.

The obvious answer would be to preload the `AVPlayerController` as soon as possible i.e. when the page loads.

However, my problem is that depending on what button the user clicks, the video must correspond correctly. Therefore, I can't preload as it is undetermined which video the user will need to see.

The function `playAnimation` gets called with the corresponding filePath of the video.

```
AVPlayer *player;
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController;

- (void) playAnimation: (NSString*)filePath {

NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
//filePath may be from the Bundle or from the Saved file Directory, it is just the path for the video
player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
playerViewController.player = player;
playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = false;

[self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:false completion:^{

    [playerViewController.player play];//Used to Play animation
}];
```

Would there be any way to load this video controller in the `viewDidLoad` before hand and then change its source and play upon request without affecting smoothness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out!

I created an `AVPlayerLayer` and then attached this to a `UIView`, the reason it works without causing a flash of black screen and looking a lot smoother to transition is because it gets initialised first with the **correct video file path**, then added as a subLayer onto a `UIView` and then I call to play the video.

Here is the code I used in the end. It may be helpful for anyone also wondering how to attach an AVPlayer to a UIView.

```
AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width;
CGFloat height = self.view.frame.size.height;
playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
```

The following code adds the `AVPlayerLayer` to the `UIView` but also adds it into an array of layers which I can use when I need to call `removeFromSuperlayer` in order to dismiss once it has finished playing.

```
[self.videoView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
[arrayOfLayers addObject:playerLayer];
[playerViewController.player play];
```

To dismiss the view once it has played, I then add a `notification observer`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playBackFinished:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:playerItem];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = player.currentItem;
```

And this is the function that gets called to dismiss the view...

```
-(void)playBackFinished:(NSNotification *) notification {
    [arrayOfLayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];
}
```